# Order of transformations?

Tags: functional-analysis, transformation

In transforming the graph $e^x$ to $e^{-2(x+2)}$, I thought the order of transformations was horizontal translation, horizontal dilation/reflection, vertical dilation/reflection and finally vertical translation (basically working inside the function, outwards). But when I graph it, it appears to have been horizontally dilated and reflected FIRST, then horizontally translated.

Answer (score 0):

$$ -2(x+2)=-2x-4$$

Therefore you have different choices.